# How this iterable works on the above list?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

```
sum((float(d['cty']) for d in mpg)) / len(mpg)
```

output: 16.86

how does the d['cty']) loop through mpg as we are dealing with a list and get value corresponding to it?

```
[OrderedDict([('', '1'),
          ('manufacturer', 'audi'),
          ('model', 'a4'),
          ('displ', '1.8'),
          ('year', '1999'),
          ('cyl', '4'),
          ('trans', 'auto(l5)'),
          ('drv', 'f'),
          ('cty', '18'),
          ('hwy', '29'),
          ('fl', 'p'),
          ('class', 'compact')]),
OrderedDict([('', '2'),
          ('manufacturer', 'audi'),
          ('model', 'a4'),
          ('displ', '1.8'),
          ('year', '1999'),
          ('cyl', '4'),
          ('trans', 'manual(m5)'),
          ('drv', 'f'),
          ('cty', '21'),
          ('hwy', '29'),
          ('fl', 'p'),
          ('class', 'compact')]),
OrderedDict([('', '3'),
          ('manufacturer', 'audi'),
          ('model', 'a4'),
          ('displ', '2'),
          ('year', '2008'),
          ('cyl', '4'),
          ('trans', 'manual(m6)'),
          ('drv', 'f'),
          ('cty', '20'),
          ('hwy', '31'),
          ('fl', 'p'),
          ('class', 'compact')])]
```

Comment: I'm not sure what answer you are looking for aside from "that's how generator expressions work".

Comment: can you explain how this is written in regular for loop, am not getting how d['cty'] can get the 18   20   21

Comment: D loops through mpg. Cty is a key. In "regular" it would be: `sum = 0 for d in mpg: sum += d['ctg'] print(float(sum)/ len(mpg))`

Answer (score 0):

It calculates average of all elements, not only for 3 values of cty but 234 list values of 'cty' and then divides from its length of a list.

Put 'cty' in a variable and print like this

ct =list(float(d['cty']) for d in mpg)
print (ct)

You'll understand.

sum(float(d['cty']) for d in mpg) if you run this only you'll get a sum 3945.00 and when you divide by length of list from 234, you'll get ans as 16.86

Answer (score -1):

Roughly speaking, the for-loop equivalent of `((float(d['cty']) for d in mpg))` would be

```
result = []
for d in mpg:
      result.append(float(d['cy'])
```

You have three elements of `mpg`. The first one has `'cty': '18'`. So when you feed in the key `'cty'`, you get the value `'18'`, which is then converted to the float `18.0`. You similarly get `21.0` and `20.0`. The sum of those is `59.0`. I don't see how that gets to `16.68`, though.

Comment: it is average I divided it by len(mpg), that is the reason its 16.68